# Analyzing multiple .xls files

Tags: python, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have around 1000 .xls files.

Each of these contain a keyword which is attached in column B in row 154. I want to collect the data for column B, row 154 until column AA. Also, there is also another keyword located in the V1 cell.

I want to create a **new** file structured as follows: For each one of the 1000 .xls files, I want in column A to contain the keyword in cell V1 (in the pre-processed files). I want the column B to contain the keyword in column B (of the pre-processed file) as well as every info from column C to column AA.

I tried using power query but could not do it because I could not make it to recognize the content of the excel files-It only recognize the name of the files. Any ideas?

Here is how I want my new excel file to look like: The date is located in the V1 cell in the old files.

[image]

Comment: **You want** a couple of things, but what have you done yourself to achieve those? Or are you asking somebody here to do your work for you? Please read [help] for what you can ask about and how you should present your question.

Comment: Hi, could you attach sample data (randomize data) as per the base (pre-processed) file and solution you want to achieve as per above base file. So it will be easier to visualize in the context. You can use free image sharing websites/ or file sharing websites to upload randomized base file and solution file and provide links here

Comment: I have used "combine & transform data" from power query although discard many of the files because of errors. When opening a file with an error the data are ok, even the rows are in the same place as the other files. So I can not interpret the background of the error.